# какой смысл хранить видео/аудио на локалке?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Хранить фото в базе данных почему то нормально а хранить видео или аудио почему то не рекомендуется-почему? и как лучше это хранить?

Comment: кто вам сказал что хранить в БД фото нормально? любой `BLOB` - это не очень хорошо для БД.

Comment: В базе данных насколько я знаю хранятся только данные о картинке, путь до неё например. Вы наверное имели ввиду не базу данных, а ваш хостинг, точнее файловую директорию? Хранить можно и видео, и фото, и аудио, вопрос в дисковом пространстве предоставленном вам хостинговой компанией. Если места предостаточно, тогда грузите конечно.

Comment: Например для видео используют такие площадки как Youtube, чисто потому-что у него свои сервера с "безграничной вместимостью", а они в свою очередь разрешают использовать их площадки, так как это для них лишние просмотры, реклама так сказать, то есть взаимовыгодные отношения)).

Comment: да я имел ввиду что файловую директорию но какой смысл заполнять место на хостинге

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хранение видео или аудио в базе данных может привести к ряду проблем, связанных с производительностью, объемом хранимых данных и сложностью обработки.

Первая проблема - производительность. Видео и аудио файлы могут быть очень большими по размеру, что может замедлить работу базы данных и повлиять на производительность всей системы.

Вторая проблема - получение файлов и их поиск. Могут возникнуть серьёзные проблемы при попытке получить файл, декодировать его и обработать на вашем языке. То есть "отдавать" видео-файл куда легче через веб-сервер, чем декодировать его к примеру из base64, обработать тем же PHP и отдать пользователю.

Не знаю с чего вы взяли, что хранят картинки в базе данных напрямую, не общайтесь с такими, они больные люди. Максимум, что разумно сделать в базе данных - это создать запись с данными файла, его вес, имя, описание, ссылка на FTP файла и прочие необходимые вам данные.

Comment: Ещё могу добавить третий пункт: отдача того же видео клиенту, через сервер его можно отдавать небольшими кусками, к примеру по 20 - 30 мб, если же это делать через ЯП из  базы данных, то у человека будет "загружатся" страница до тех пор, пока сервер не обработает весь файл и не отдаст его клиенту. В нормальном случаи всё уйдет в таймаут. Можно написать ещё десяток недостатков, но этих двух-трех хватит, чтобы понять, что хранить подобные данные в БД - не лучшая затея.